# PowerApps DropDown list connection to Azure

Tags: azure, powerapps

I'm trying to get a DropDown list in my PowerApps app to connect its Items to a specific group of users, with help of  Azure.
In other words: populate the DropDown with a list of names, e.g. the members of the Economics group I have created elsewhere.
Apparently, following the link: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Import-a-List-of-users-from-Azure-AD-Group/td-p/54160 ,
in PowerApps this is not working as-is:

```
Items = AzureAD.GetGroupMembers("xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx").value
```

(Error: "Calling an unknown or not supported function").
I suspect I have to go to the Azure portal and enable something in Azure AD to get it to work, but I feel a bit intimidated before the sheer amount of settings and options
available here. Could anybody please give some guidance?

EDIT: I must not necessarily have Azure doing this (someway it feels like calling the fire department to fill a glass of water for me). If I could do it some other way, feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the AzureAD.GetGroupMembers will be recognised in your app, you have to:

1. [Add Azure AD to your connections in the PowerApps portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-manage-connections)
2. [Add the Azure AD connection to your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-data-connection)

Comment: Great! Thank you! It is working, much simpler than I thought, just needed to adjust the Value property in the Dropdown to "displayName".